# Invalid cast exception on using virtual method with base class being the run time type c#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I know this is nothing new, I just want to know why this throws an InvalidCastException since the runtime type here (A which is the base class) has an implementation for that method, thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = (B)new A();
        Console.WriteLine(b.Foo());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A
{
    public virtual string Foo() => "Hello from base class";
}

class B : A
{
    public override string Foo() => "Hello from sub class";
}
```

Comment: `new A()` is not an instance of `B`.

Comment: When learning, use common names instead of single-letter labels, say Animal for A and Bird for B.  Naturally, Bird is an Animal.  So, your "B b = (B)new A()" becomes "Bird bird = (Bird)new Animal()" - now you can immediately see that that doesn't make sense - Animal could well abstract, and (from what Lee says) Animals could well be something other than Birds.

Comment: I know that when I say new A() it's still a reference to an instance of A which is why I said that the runtime type is still A, maybe I wasn't clear with my question, my question is why does it throw an InvalidCastException on calling b.Foo() instead of calling the base class' Foo() (A.Foo())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because `A` is the base class of `B` doesn't change that `A` isn't `B`. It's `B` who's `A`.

For example, you're a mix of your dad and you mother, but you're not your dad or your mother. If the police gets you doing something wrong with your car, would the police ask for your dad's or mom's driving license?

You can compare the *police* with the compiler. The compiler won't accept that you set an instance of `A` in a reference typed as `B`, because they're different types.

What compiler can accept is that an instance of `B` upcasted to `A` could be set to a reference of `A`:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
b = (B)a;
```

Comment: Ok, I get it now, it's just that the way downcasting is explained in "C#6 In A Nutshell" got me kind of confused, thanks.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa No problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast base class to derived. It's possible that `B` declares some new member (e.g. method `M1`) which are absent in `A`. And if it was possible to cast, if you call `M1` method for `A`, it would be absent. So the runtime prevents such casting.